# Bad audio even after modifying daemon.conf

Tags: sound, alsa

I just started to use **Ubuntu**. Everything is good except for the audio. It sounds like it's coming out of a tin can. So, I Googled how to fix it, an AskUbuntu thread suggested modifying the **daemon.conf** file.

I tried doing that but it didn't work. Is there any other way to fix it?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? Desktop or Server?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS